# Is there an ESLint rule that does the same as 'no-floating-promises' did in the now deprecated TSLint?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I'm migrating several projects from TSLint to ESLint and I've found that ESLint has no rule to prevent promises from being handled correctly, or at least I haven't found it in the docs.

The *no-floating-promises* rule in TSLint forced the programmer to, either `async/await`, or `then/catch` all promises. Is there a way to get that same functionality in ESLint?

I am aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63069344/can-eslint-help-you-prevent-unhandled-promise-rejections), but I think OP is referring to a rule with a different behavior: `catch()` all promises. Moreover, the answer to that question is the npm package [eslint-plugin-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-promise), which hasn't had a release in two years.

Answer (score 2):

[typescript-eslint plugin](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) has a [rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-floating-promises.md) that forces all promises to be handled correctly.

With ESLint installed:

Install the typescript-eslint plugin:

```
npm i --save-dev eslint typescript @typescript-eslint/parser @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
```

Add it to your current configuration of ESLint:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: [
    '@typescript-eslint',
  ],
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
  ],
};
```

> If you chose "enforce popular coding style" and chose "Standard" when installing ESLint, you probably have this plugin installed. Albeit, if you have doubts, check your ESLint config file.

And add the rule to your rules object:

```
// .eslintrc.js
/* the rest of the configuration */
rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": "error",
    /* the rest of the rules */
}
```